# Find minimum value in dynamic array in C

Tags: c

I am completely new in C. My task is to find minimum value in each row and after that execute some transformations with matrix. I work with dynamic 2d array but suddenly appeared misunderstanding with pointers. Visual Studio shows me such list of errors which are connected with function `min`:

```
Warning 2   warning C4047: ':' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
Warning 1   warning C4047: '<' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
Warning 3   warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

I have no ideas why these errors occured.

```
    void transformMatrix(int** arr, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        int i,j;
        int minElem;
        for (i=0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            minElem = min (arr[i], colCount);
            for (j=0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
                if (i%2 ==0) 
                {
                    arr[i][j] -= minElem;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i][j] += minElem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int min(int* arr, int elemCount)
    {
        int minEl = arr[0];
        int i;
        for (i=1; i < elemCount; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i]<minEl)
            {
                minEl = arr[i];
            }
        }

        return minEl;
    }
```

Comment: `minElem = min (arr[i], colCount);` between `min` and `(`, the space is intended?

Comment: @Matputer Althought I too think it's ugly and disturbing (*not as much as `int* arr`*), it's valid. So, what's your point?

Comment: No, it was accidentally. I've removed this space and nothing has changed.

Comment: Im sorry. I didn't know that it is valid.

Comment: @Natasha, the space would have nothing to do with it because it's ignored by the compiler. The problem does not appear to be in the code you posted.  Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't understand why I have errors when I call function "min" in "transformMatrix" and therefore don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You code looks fine. But still lets change int * to int aa[]. Moreover post complete log of errors.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler tell you the line number of the error?

Comment: @Mazhar, I've tried to change int * to int aa[], it didn't help. Also I added complete log of errors

Comment: @stark, error C2059 points at `int min(int* arr, int elemCount)`; other warnings point at `minElem = min (arr[i], colCount);`

Comment: Are you sure the name `min` isn't defined by something else?

Answer (score 1):

The function `min` identifier is already used in MSVC's `stdlib.h` as a macro

```
#define min(a,b)    (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Rename your function to something else.

Comment: Thanks a million! It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

No errors found. This is your code I run with the following result and worked fine. If it still gives it, inform me. So that I could remove it.

Result

```
12      13      14                                                                                                                                                                                               
13      14      15                                                                                                                                                                                               
14      15      16                                                                                                                                                                                               
Transforming     

0       1       2                                                                                                                                                                                                
1       2       3                                                                                                                                                                                                
2       3       4 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


    int min(int* arr, int elemCount)
    {
        int minEl = arr[0];
        int i;
        for (i=1; i < elemCount; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i]<minEl)
            {
                minEl = arr[i];
            }
        }

        return minEl;
    }

   void transformMatrix(int** arr, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        int i,j;
        int minElem;
        for (i=0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            minElem = min (arr[i], colCount);
            for (j=0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
                if (i%2 ==0) 
                {
                    arr[i][j] -= minElem;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i][j] += minElem;
                }
            }
        }
    }



int main()
{
   int **aray;
   aray = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 3);
   aray[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
   aray[1] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
   aray[2] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {

    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
         aray[i][j] = i+j+12;
         printf("%d \t", aray[i][j]);
      }
   printf("\n");
   }

   printf("Transforming \n");
   transformMatrix(aray, 3, 3);

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {

    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
      aray[i][j] = i+j;
      printf("%d \t", aray[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
   }

    return 0;
}
```